# ubuntu 22.04 not detecting headphones

Tags: sound, 22.04

Headphones set as unplugged when plugged.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem also appears on my computer upgraded to the `22.04`.

Fisrtly,Summons the volume control window:

```shell
pavucontrol
```

Secondly, switch to the `output devices` tab
,just change the port to `Headphones`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. However, the cause was different. I noticed that the dmesg command requires admin privileges sudo dmesg.

Therefore, based on the solution provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390187), I executed the following command in my terminal to make it work.

```
$ sudo sysctl kernel.dmesg_restrict=0
```